# add overlay on picture

Tags: css

I would like to transform a div to apply it in front of a panel.

```
position: absolute;
font-size: 28px;
top: 203px;
left: 149px;
width: 661px;
height: 384px;
-webkit-transform: skewY(4.1deg) rotate(1deg);
background-color: red;
```

[image]

but on bottom right the div doesn't fill to the background.

What is the css property to set it correctly ?

Comment: Why don't you make a PNG image and make that part transparent? Then you could put this div behind that image. Also, can you give us the actual HTML behind this?

Comment: In the red div I will add custom text. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKwJVd

Answer (score 1):

You can add skewX to your css.
I tried this and almost filled the shape :

```
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 28px;
    top: 203px;
    left: 149px;
    width: 641px;
    height: 354px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(4.1deg) rotate(1deg) skewX(2deg);
    background-color: red;
```

Comment: His solution fills more of the shape than you do.

Comment: maybe , but we should change both parameters (skewX and skewY) to find out correct one , and i tried it in Firefox inspector . for me it was good :)

Answer (score 0):

This code fixes the bottom right corner and takes other answers into consideration:

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  background-image: url('http://www.radiomelodie.com/actus/actu-08062017id7801.jpg');
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 28px;
  top: 200px;
  left: 149px;
  width: 665px;
  height: 395px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg) skewX(1deg) rotate(0.9deg);
  background: linear-gradient(359.2deg, transparent 6%, red 6%)
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```